# AWS SQS JS SDK - how to change receive maxbatchsize client limit?

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-batch

I am querying SQS queue in batches from NodeJS and trying to increase receive batch size, which is limited to 10. I see that it is possible top increase the limit on SQS server and in java sdk, see [maxBatchSize](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-client-side-buffering-request-batching.html), but don't see the way to do it in [JS sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html). Is there any reason to have this limit and not allow to change it?

Comment: Are you asking how to set it in JS, or are you asking how to set it to a value larger than 10?

Comment: I am asking how to set it to more then 10, cause when I am trying to receive MaxNumberOfMessages  more then 10,  getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

Look again at the page you cited for Java.

> The default value of this setting is 10 requests per batch, which is also the maximum batch size currently allowed by Amazon SQS.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-client-side-buffering-request-batching.html

The SQS service does not support larger values than 10.

Comment: Interesting, why the limit is so small. Especially aws server allows config change to go higher

Comment: No, @DennisR, [it doesn't](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html).  The service will only give you 10 messages at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum is 10, and that also is not a guarantee, sometimes i recieve 6, 7 etc. I have a batching requirement(java) so i call

```
result = bufferedSqs.receiveMessage(new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl));
```

multiple times till i get a required count of messages or till

```
result.getMessages().isEmpty()
```

returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the js sdk MaxNumberOfMessages and the max limit is 10.

And if you need to read more than 10 messages. I would suggest you use Kinesis Data Stream where you can hold your data and read it in multiple ways.

SQS JS SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html

Kinesis: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-consumers.html